# How to divide an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So lets say I have this array var:

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d","a","b","a","b","a"]
```

and so on the way `a` will appear is just random 
I want to divide this array from one `a` to the next `a` 
for example my new array could be like

```
[["a","b","c","d"],["a","b"],["a","b"],["a"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to achieve that?

Comment: Why don't you do it? What is bothering you here? You didn't provide any code. :/

Comment: The bare minimum code expected here is a simple `for` loop and check if the current character is `"a"`. Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: @Meet Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am sorry i didnt share my code ,

Comment: @MeetBorda you can share it now, just edit your question

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce the array and push a new array to the result if you have the wanted value. Then push all values to the last array in the result set.

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"],
    result = array.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        if (!i || v === 'a') r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am wondering about what is result if first element of array is not `"a"` ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha that's an invalid scenario since the characters are always sorted alphabetically "*from `a` to the next `a`*"

Comment: @SudhirOjha, i added a check for the first item.

Comment: @B001ᛦ you suprisingly get much more points by answering easy off-topic questions or blatant duplicate than obscure interesting ones..

Answer (score 1):

You can convert array to string and then use `match()` and `RegExp`. Then then use `map()` to get array of arrays

```js
let arr = ["a","b","c","d","a","b","a","b","a"]

let res = arr.join('').match((/a[^a]+/g)).map(x => [...x]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `split()/join()` methods like:

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"];
let r = arr.join('').split('a').map(x => (["a", ...x.split('')]));
r.shift();

console.log(r);
```

Comment: The second `+a` is extra `arr.join('').split('a').map(x => (["a",...x.split('')]));`. Just add `"a"` in `map()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @MaheerAli ... Updated.

Answer (score 0):

A succinct method is to join your characters into a string, then split on each `a` using a positive lookahead regex to keep the `a` in the split parts, and finally split the resulting parts into arrays:

```js
const arr = ["a","b","c","d","a","b","a","b","a"];

const result = arr.join('').split(/(?=a)/).map(x => x.split(''));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following.

First convert array to string:- `"abcdababa" (using .join(""))`

Now split string with "a" as seprator:- `["","bcd","b","b",""] (using .split("a"))`

Now prepend "a" to all the element:- `["a","abcd","ab","ab","a"] (using .map(x=>"a"+x))`

Now split all element with ""(empty string) as seprator:- `[["a"],["a","b","c","d"],["a","b"],["a","b"],["a"]] (using .split("")) (this step will be inside map function)`

Now remove first element(as it is not part of your string):- `[["a","b","c","d"],["a","b"],["a","b"],["a"]] (using .shift())`

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","a","b","a","b","a"];
var x1 = arr.join("").split("a").map(x => {
  x = "a" + x;
  return x.split("");
});
x1.shift();
console.log(x1);
```

Answer (score 0):

using simple `forEach`

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"];
var result = [];
var i = -1;

arr.forEach(function(val) {
    if (val == 'a') {
        result.push([]);
        i++;
    }
    result[i].push(val);
})

console.log(result);
```